# Cant put sqLite query in tableAdapter

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, tableadapter

I have a question for you guys.
I have an sqlite query that i test on SqlFiddle and i know it work, but i cant put it in a table adapter in Vb.net.

here's my query:

```
select cola, colb,
SUM(case when (tbl = 'a') then 1 else 0 END) as TableA,
SUM(case when (tbl = 'b') then 1 else 0 END) as TableB,
SUM(case when (tbl = 'c') then 1 else 0 END) as TableC
from
(
    select cola,colb,'a' as tbl
    from TableA
    union all
    select cola, colb,'b' as tbl
    from TableB
    union all
    select cola, colb,'c' as tbl
    from TableC
) d
group by cola, colb
```

The error that i get in Visual studio 2010 is:
Error in select clause: expression near 'END'
Missing FROM clause
Error in select clause: expression near ','
Error in select clause: expression near 'FROM'
Unable to parse query text.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.